# Concentration inequalities for gaussian variables

Tags: normal-distribution, probability-inequalities

How would you prove this?

$$\mathbb{P}\left[\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-\mu\right| \leq \sigma\sqrt\frac{2\log(2\delta)} {n}\right]\geq 1 - \delta$$

Assuming that $x_1...x_n$ are independent Gaussian RVs with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

Comment: I think there's a mistake in your formula. As it stands, $\delta$ could be quite close to $0$ which would lead to $\log(2\delta)$ being negative.

Comment: First reduce it to a statement about the standard Normal variable $X=\frac{1}{\sigma}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i - \mu\right)$, thereby eliminating all appearances of $n, \mu,$ and $\sigma$. That should make it obvious that the assertion is false even for meaningful values of $\delta$: plugging in $\delta=1/2$, for instance, produces the assertion $\Pr(|X|\le 0) \ge 1/2$.

Comment: The simple bound $Q(x)< \frac 12\exp(-x^2/2)$ for $x>0$ should suffice to prove a more reasonable version of what you want to prove.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got a random variable $\bar X_n \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$ and you're looking to quantify the probability that $\bar X_n$ is a certain distance from its mean. This means you'll want to make use of a [concentration inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality).

I'm going to prove a result that is very similar to your question but with some modifications so that it is actually true. I will show that
$$
\mathbb P\left( \big\vert \bar X_n - \mu \big\vert > \sigma \sqrt{\frac{-4\log(\delta / \sqrt 2)}{n}} \right) < \delta
$$
for $0 < \delta < 1$.

We know that $\bar X_n - \mu \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma^2/n)$ so $\frac{n}{\sigma^2}|\bar X_n - \mu | ^2 \sim \chi^2_1$ If $Y \sim \chi^2_\nu$ then the MGF of $Y$ is
$$
M_Y(t) = E(e^{tY}) = (1-2t)^{-\nu/2}.
$$ Now by Chernoff's bound we have
$$
\mathbb P\left( \frac{n}{\sigma^2} \big\vert \bar X_n - \mu \big\vert^2 > \log \left(4 \delta^{-4}\right) \right) < \frac{(1-2t)^{-1/2}}{(4 \delta^{-4})^t} = \delta
$$ 
if we let $t = \frac 14$.

Comment: I think that that $\log(4\delta^{-4})$ in the last displayed equation should be $\displaystyle\sqrt{\log(4\delta^{-4})}$, maybe?  Also, could you provide a link to where you got the specific form of Chernoff bound for the $\chi^2$ random variable? I am more used to seeing it in the form $$P\{X > x\} < \min_{\lambda >0} e^{-\lambda x}M_X(\lambda).$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate I don't think there's a missing square root -- I start off with $\sqrt{-4 \log (\delta / \sqrt 2)}$ and then square both sides. And I'm using the form of Chernoff's bound given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality#Chernoff_bounds

Comment: OK, I understand why there is no missing square root (you are working with $P(Z^2 > z^2)$ instead of $P(|Z| > z)$), but I am still puzzled as to where that $4\delta^{-4}$ came from and whether $t=\frac 14$ does indeed give the minimum value of the Chernoff bound.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ denote a standard normal random variable. As the comments and Chaconne's answer have noted, the question here is to bound $P\{|X| > x\} = 2Q(x)$ where $Q(x) = 1 - \Phi(x)$ is the complementary normal distribution function. Now, a well-known bound is
$$ Q(x)  < \frac 12e^{-x^2/2} ~~ \text{for } x > 0 \tag{1}$$
which immediately gives
$$P\{|X| > x\} < e^{-x^2/2}, \tag{2}$$
or, writing $\delta$ for the right side of $(2)$,
$$P\left\{|X| > \sqrt{-2\ln(\delta)}\right\} < \delta \tag{3}$$
Note that this is different from @Chaconne's result
$\displaystyle P\left\{|X| > \sqrt{-4 \ln (\delta/\sqrt{2})}\right\} < \delta$.

---

**Proof of $(1)$:** Let $Y \sim N(0,1)$ be independent of $X$. Then, for $x>0$,
$$P\{|X| > x, |Y| > x\} = 4[Q(x)]^2 < P\{X^2+Y^2 > 2x^2\}.$$
But $X^2+Y^2$ is an exponential random variable with parameter $\frac 12$
and so 
$$P\{X^2+Y^2 > 2x^2\} = e^{-\frac 12\cdot 2x^2} = e^{-x^2}\implies Q(x) < \frac 12e^{-x^2/2}.$$

---

**Chernoff bound on $Q(x)$:** For every choice of $\lambda > 0$, 
$\mathbf 1_{\{t\colon t > x \}} < e^{\lambda (t-x)}$ and so
$$P\{X > x\} = E[\mathbf 1_{\{X\colon X > x \}}]  < 
E[e^{\lambda (X-x)}] = e^{-\lambda x}E[e^{\lambda X}]
= e^{-\lambda x}\cdot e^{\lambda^2/2}$$ 
leading to
$$P\{X > x\} \leq 
\min_{\lambda >0}\exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{2} - x \lambda\right)
= e^{-x^2/2}$$
since the minimum occurs at $\lambda = x$. This gives
$$P\left\{|X| > \sqrt{-2\ln (\delta/2)}\right\}  < \delta. \tag{4}$$
This is weaker than $(3)$ but it too is different from Chaconne's result.